# Let $p: N\rightarrow N$ be such that $p(m)<p(n)$ whenever $m<n$.Let $\sum_{i=0}^na_n$ and $\sum_{i=0}^nb_n$ be 2 series of numbers related as follows

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Let $p: N\rightarrow N$ be such that $p(m)<p(n)$ whenever $m<n$. let $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^n b_n$ be two series of numbers related as follows:

$b_1 = a_1+a_2+a_3+..+a_{p(1)}$,
$b_{n+1} = a_{p(n)+1} + a_{p(n)+2} +...+ a_{p(n+1)}$,
for $n$ greater than equal to 1.

Assume that there is a constant $M>0$  such that $p(n+1)-p(n)<M$ for all $n$ and assume that $\lim_\limits{n\to\infty}a_n=0$.

Prove that $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum_{n=1}^n b_n$ converges and they converge to a same sum when they do.

Let p(n) = n^2.
Then $b_1 = a_1$
$b_2=a_2 +a_4+a_4$
$b_3= a_5+a_6+a_7+a_8+a_9$
Clearly $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n $ =$\sum_{n=1}^n b_n.$

Then assume there is a constant M>0 such that p(n+1)−p(n)<M for all n
and assume that limn→∞ an=0. This shows us that a1 is finite $\sum_{n=1}^n a_n $ is finite hence converges.

But I don't think that it is solid proof for convergence so plz tell  me a better method to prove convergence.

Comment: Show your work: one implication is easy. For the converse try $p(n)=2n.$ Hurry up before your post gets closed.

Comment: If $p(n) = n^2$, you have $p(n+1) - p(n) = 2n+1$ which is unbounded, which violates one of the conditions in the problem statement.

Comment: The tricky part is that $\sum a_n$ may be conditionally convergent. For example, maybe $a_n = (-1)^n / n$, so if you summed in order it converges, but if you first summed the odd terms before the even terms, you'd get $-\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$S_n=\sum_{i=1}^na_i,\quad R_n=\sum_{j=1}^nb_j$$ Let $p(0)=0.$ Then $$R_n=\sum_{j=1}^n\ \sum_{k=p(j-1)+1}^{p(j)}a_k=\sum_{k=1}^{p(n)}a_k=S_{p(n)}$$
If the sequence $S_n$ is convergent, so is $R_n=S_{p(n)}$ and the limits are equal. Observe that for $n$ there exists the unique $m$ so that $$p(m-1)\le n< p(m)$$ Then $$R_m-S_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{p(m)}a_k$$ hence $$|S_n-R_m|\le \sum_{k=p(m-1)+1}^{p(m)}|a_k|=:A_m$$ When $n\to \infty,$ then $m\to \infty.$ As $a_k\to 0$ and $A_m$ contains at most $M$ terms, we conclude that $A_m\to 0.$ Therefore if  $R_m\to R,$ then $S_n\to R.$